# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput Resolution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to specify output size to be 960x720 in video settings.  However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()  
if self.session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput!) {  
    self.session.addOutput(videoDataOutput!)   
    self.videoDataOutput!.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),  
                                           kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: 960,  
                                           kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: 720] as [String : Any]  

}
```

Any other way to get the video data output in a custom lower resolution?

Answer (score 1):

For sorry you should adhere to any of these presets

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/preset

or use this library to scale it

https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevelSessionExporter

And this is the relevant part

```
let exporter = NextLevelSessionExporter(withAsset: asset) 
exporter.videoOutputConfiguration = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodec.h264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 720),
    AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 960),
    AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionDict
]
```

Comment: Most of the presents push you to 16:9 ratio's.  Documentation does not specify that kCVPixelBufferHeightKey and kCVPixelBufferWidthKey would be ommited on iOS

Comment: it works in buffer writing for example when writing an image with a specific dimensions , but here it's intentionally omitted because of the presets